# Import OpenCv module in Python, all packages already installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, python-module

I have installed both opencv 3.0.0 and python 2.7 (through Anaconda 2.2.0) in my Ubuntu 14 system. I usually use this environment to work with Caffe by using the python wrapper.
Now I need to use opencv in Python to process videos, thus I want to use the python bindings of opencv.
But when I try to import the opencv module by typing "import cv2" (or cv or cv2.cv) in the python environment I get the following message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

so I tried to install python-opencv via

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

as suggested in other topics. But python still doesn't import the opencv module. As an hint, I post the following outputs from the commands to check the opencv version and the python-opencv version (that is not found). Also, I tried to find the package python-opencv by using dpkg -l and I found it.
So, How can I import opencv in python ? And what about the mentioned 'python-opencv.pc' file?

```
 :~$pkg-config --modversion opencv
 3.0.0
 :~$ pkg-config --modversion python-opencv
Package python-opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `python-opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'python-opencv' found
:~$ dpkg -l |grep python-opencv
ii  python-opencv
2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 amd64 Python bindings for the computer vision library
```

Comment: This tutorial might be helpful: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I ve read this tutorial, but I don t find the solution. Do you suggest to making the opencv installation again? My opencv installation compiled successfully and i ve already installed numpy. So i don t understand what the point is.. btw i followed this guidehttp://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: What does python --version yield? And where is cv2.so stored?

Comment: there is not any cv2.so and by "python --version" I get Python 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)

Comment: To whom it may concern after the above commands I've put the pc off and on again. I've looked for any "log file" of the last opencv building with the aim to discover if the python wrapper has been compiled. I found that the last created file is install_manifest.txt which have a row "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so". So I ve checked it and I found the file right there! I've tried to do "import cv2" and "cv2.__version__" in python and it worked!! I'm happy that I figured out but it should be better understand the reason why